Google Drive search field does not appear for Outlook guest users
I need to share a Google Drive directory with some users whose domains are in Outlook. However, the Drive search field does not appear for these users. In image 1 is how Drive appears to these users:
Drive
Is there anything that can be done?

Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.
